# Convergence of $\sigma-$algebra for converging stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times

Given a filtration, ${\mathcal{F}_t},t\in[0,\infty).$ Let $T_n$ be a sequence of stopping time that converges to $T$ and $T_n\le T_{n+1}.$ We have correpsonding $\sigma-$algebra, ${\mathcal{F}_{T_n}}$ and $\mathcal{F}_T.$

Now, denote $\mathcal{F}'=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_{T_n}:n=1,2,\cdots),$ i.e., the $\sigma-$algebra generated by all $\mathcal{F}_{T_n}$.

**Q: Will $\mathcal{F}'=\mathcal{F}_T$ holds?**

I believe the condition that the filtration is left continuous is needed, since one can take $T_n,T$ to be constant. Let's assume that.

---

My try:

- That $\mathcal{F}'\subset\mathcal{F}_T$ is trivial, since all $\mathcal{F}_{T_n}\subset\mathcal{F}_T$ by $T_n\le T$. We left to show $\mathcal{F}_T\subset\mathcal{F}'.$
- By definition, $A\in\mathcal{F}_T$ is equivalent to $A\cap\{T\le t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$ for any $t$. How can one deduce from here that $A\in \mathcal{F}'.$ Got stuck here.
- In [Approximation of a unbounded stopping time and convergence of respective $\sigma$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048145/approximation-of-a-unbounded-stopping-time-and-convergence-of-respective-sigmam), saz gives an approach for discrete time. For $A\in\mathcal{F}_T, A$ can be decomposed as,
  $$A = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A\cap\{T\le n\})\cup(A\cap\{T=\infty\}) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\cup A_\infty.$$
  Then show $A_n\in\mathcal{F}_{T_n}.$ We have $A_n\in\mathcal{F}_n, $ we require to show $A_n\cap\{T_n\le t\}\in\mathcal{F_t},$ this is so if $t\ge n$ since $\{T_n\le t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$. But how about $t<n?$ I was stuck here.

---

Update:
One can define, $\mathcal{F}_{S-}=$ the $\sigma-$algebra generated by $\mathcal{F}_{0+}=\cap_{s>0}\mathcal{F}_s$ and the sets $\{S>t\}\cap\mathcal{F_t}.$ then when $S=s$ is a constant, $\mathcal{F}_{S-}=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_u:u<s)=\mathcal{F}_{s-}.$ So this is simply the generalization of left limit. Then one can prove that, 
$$\mathcal{F}_{T-}=\mathcal{F}'.$$

So now, the question may become to show,
$$ \mathcal{F}_{T-}=\mathcal{F}_{T} .$$

---

Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion $\mathcal F'\subset \mathcal F_T$ may be strict.

**Example:** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ be a probability space on which is defined a standard normal random variable $Z$. (So that $\Bbb P[Z=0]=0$.) Let $(\mathcal F_t)$ be the filtration generated by the process $X$ defined by
$$
X_t=\cases{1,&$0\le t<1$,\cr  Z,&$t\ge 1$.\cr}
$$
For $T_n$ take the constant $1-1/n$, and then $T=1$. Yiu have $\mathcal F_{T_n}=\mathcal F' = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ for all $n$, but $\mathcal F_T=\sigma\{Z\}$.
The key here is that $T$ is predictable, and "something new" happens at time $T$.

Comment: I agree with you that the inclusion may be strict, but your example doesn't work because the OP is assuming that $\mathcal{F}_t = \mathcal{F}_{t-}$ for all $t$.

Comment: Missed that.  To make an example with random $T$, start a Brownian motion at 0 and run it until the time $T$ that it first hits 1.  At that time have the process jump to a random position independent of the past, with a standard normal law, and then stay there forever.